# recursive mysql procedure for getting a referral branch

Tags: mysql, procedure, mysql-5.7

I recently got acquainted with procedures and functions in mysql and still don't quite understand how they work. I'm trying to make a referral branch to display on the site.

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE fb2_get_referrals (IN refer_id INT UNSIGNED, IN parent_level INT UNSIGNED, OUT return_path MEDIUMTEXT)
         BEGIN
            DECLARE parent_id INT UNSIGNED;
            DECLARE path_result MEDIUMTEXT;
            DECLARE referral_offset INT UNSIGNED;
            DECLARE count_user_referrals INT UNSIGNED;
            
            SET referral_offset = 0;
            SET parent_level = parent_level + 1;
            SET count_user_referrals = (SELECT COUNT(fb2_users.id) FROM fb2_users WHERE fb2_users.referral_id = refer_id);
            
            IF(count_user_referrals > 0) THEN
                label1: WHILE referral_offset < count_user_referrals DO
                    SELECT 
                        CONCAT( 
                            '{',
                            '"id":',fb2_users.id,',',
                            '"level":',parent_level,
                            '}'
                        ) as path,
                        fb2_users.id as pi,
                        parent_level as pl
                    INTO return_path, parent_id, parent_level
                    FROM fb2_users 
                    WHERE fb2_users.referral_id = refer_id 
                    LIMIT 1 OFFSET referral_offset;
                    
                    CALL fb2_get_referrals(parent_id, parent_level, path_result);
                    SELECT CONCAT(path_result, return_path) INTO return_path;
                   
                    SET referral_offset = referral_offset + 1;
                END WHILE label1;
            END IF;
         END$$
```

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getPath(user_id INT) RETURNS MEDIUMTEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE res MEDIUMTEXT;
    CALL fb2_get_referrals(user_id,0, res);
    RETURN res;
END$$
```

| id | r_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 9 | 7 |

as a result, I get null

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), paragraphs 5 and 3.

Comment: You must use temptable and collect the data into it over the iterations selecting the whole dataset with single query finally.